# virtuoso-opensource 7.1: how do I build an ubuntu deb package, from github source, that includes isql?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, virtuoso

Does anyone know how to create a virtuoso-opensource 7.1 ubuntu deb package, from source, that includes isql?

**If I do a `make install` from the source, `virtuoso-t` and `isql` are installed to the `/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin` folder, however, if I do a `dpkg-buildpackage` on the same source, it only installs `/usr/bin/virtuoso-t` but `isql` is not included.**

### Make install of 7.1 (which includes isql)

```
 apt-get install -y bison libtool flex gperf autoconf gawk make libssl-dev wget unzip
 wget --no-check-certificate -q https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/archive/develop/7.zip -O virtuoso-opensource.zip
 unzip -q virtuoso-opensource.zip
 cd virtuoso-opensource
 ./autogen
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

The results are a `bin` directory with `virtuoso-t`, **`isql`**, `isqlw`, etc:

```
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/bin/:
total 13544
-rw-r--r-- 1       95 Sep  8 12:06 backup.sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1    31840 Jun 18 15:39 inifile
-rwxr-xr-x 1   518984 Jun 18 15:39 isql
-rwxr-xr-x 1   649128 Jun 18 15:39 isqlw
-rwxr-xr-x 1   439856 Jun 18 15:39 virt_mail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 12214992 Jun 18 15:39 virtuoso-t
```

### Package and installation of 7.1 (which does not have `isql`)

However, if I build a deb package from the same source as above and install it, I only get `/usr/bin/virtuoso-t` and not `isql`, `isqlw`, etc.

```
 apt-get install -y bison libtool flex gperf autoconf gawk make libssl-dev wget unzip
 apt-get install -y build-essential debhelper autotools-dev automake net-tools m4 libreadline-dev openssl
 wget --no-check-certificate -q https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/archive/develop/7.zip -O virtuoso-opensource.zip
 unzip -q virtuoso-opensource.zip
 cd virtuoso-opensource
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
 cd ..
 dpkg -i virtuoso-opensource_7.1_amd64.deb
```

NOTE: [Nolan Nichols has published a dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/nicholsn/virtuoso/dockerfile/) that builds a virtuoso-opensource 7.1 server (although it too does not have `isql`).

### Package of 6.1 server (which includes `isql`)

Openlink has [instructions for doing exactly what I would like to do but for an older version](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes) and I haven't been able to figure out how to adapt these instructions to 7.1.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo aptitude install dpkg-dev build-essential
 mkdir C
 cd C
 apt-get source virtuoso-opensource
 cd virtuoso-opensource-6.1.2+dfsg1/
 sudo aptitude build-dep virtuoso-opensource
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
 ls
      libvirtodbc0_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
      libvirtuoso5.5-cil_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
      virtuoso-minimal_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-nepomuk_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-opensource-6.0_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-opensource-6.1.2+dfsg1
      virtuoso-opensource_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-opensource_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.changes
      virtuoso-opensource_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4.diff.gz
      virtuoso-opensource_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4.dsc
      virtuoso-opensource_6.1.2+dfsg1.orig.tar.gz
      virtuoso-opensource-6.1_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
      virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
      virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
      virtuoso-server_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-bpel_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-conductor_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-demo_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-doc_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-isparql_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-ods_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-cartridges_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-sparqldemo_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-syncml_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vad-tutorial_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
      virtuoso-vsp-startpage_6.1.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
```

Comment: You can get Virtuoso 7.1 DEB package via the [Linked Data Stack repository](http://stack.linkeddata.org/download/). For guidance how to create the DEB package yourself, maybe the repository maintainers can help (linkeddatastack@googlegroups.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Build virtuoso-opensource 7.2 DEB packages from github source

Thanks to [Jan-Marcek](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/350) and [stain](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/342), who both posted on github, I was able to compile virtuoso-opensource 7.2 from source using the following on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 server system:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y openjdk-6-jdk git build-essential automake
mkdir -p /tmp/build && cd /tmp/build
git clone https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource.git
cd /tmp/build/virtuoso-opensource
git checkout v7.2.0.1
deps=$(dpkg-checkbuilddeps 2>&1 | sed 's/.*: //' | sed 's/([^)]*)//g') && apt-get install -y $deps
fakeroot debian/rules clean binary
```

When the build completes the following are created in `/tmp/build/`

```
libvirtjdbc0_7.2_amd64.deb                  
virtuoso-vad-bpel_7.2_all.deb
libvirtodbc0_7.2_amd64.deb                  
virtuoso-vad-conductor_7.2_all.deb
libvirtuoso5.5-cil_7.2_amd64.deb            
virtuoso-vad-demo_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-minimal_7.2_all.deb                
virtuoso-vad-doc_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-nepomuk_7.2_all.deb                
virtuoso-vad-isparql_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-opensource                         
virtuoso-vad-ods_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-opensource_7.2_all.deb             
virtuoso-vad-rdfmappers_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-opensource-7_7.2_amd64.deb         
virtuoso-vad-sparqldemo_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-opensource-7-bin_7.2_amd64.deb     
virtuoso-vad-syncml_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-opensource-7-common_7.2_amd64.deb  
virtuoso-vad-tutorial_7.2_all.deb
virtuoso-server_7.2_all.deb                 
virtuoso-vsp-startpage_7.2_all.deb
```

## Install from DEB packages

```
dpkg -i *.deb  # might fail because of missing dependencies
apt-get -f install -y  # fixes dependencies and continues installation
```

**Now isql is available in `/usr/bin/` !!**

## Usage

```
/etc/init.d/virtuoso-opensource-7 {start|stop|force-stop|restart|force-reload|status}

/usr/bin/isql-vt <HOST>[:<PORT>] <UID> <PWD> file1 file2 ...
```

## Install from repo

I also found out that [Virtuoso 7.2 is part of OpenDataNode](http://www.comsode.eu/index.php/2014/06/open-data-node-what-it-is-what-it-does-what-is-next/) and can be installed from their repo.

```
echo "deb http://packages.comsode.eu/debian wheezy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odn.list
wget -O - http://packages.comsode.eu/key/odn.gpg.key | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install -y virtuoso-opensource=7.2
```

Comment: Note that OpenDataNode appears to have gone stagnant, while Virtuoso updates continue.